# Laravel connection of two tables and sum of columns for a given pivot

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tanulky stars and videos and relationships in the model

// in Star model

```
public function videos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class);
    }
```

and
// in Video model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

If I do `$stars = Star::with('videos')->get();`, the actor (stars) and the movies he starred in (videos) will be listed. I am attaching a json sample.

```
    [{"id":1,"name":"Marek","videos":
    [{"id":2,"user_id":1,"title":"ferwg","visitors":94,"pivot":{"star_id":1,"video_id":2}},
{"id":3,"user_id":1,"title":"fgtf","visitors":17,"pivot":{"star_id":1,"video_id":3}}
    ]}...
```

I have a visitors item in the videos table.How can I find out the total number of visitors for each actor (stars) for the movies he/she starred in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collect($stars->first()['videos'])->sum(visitors);
```

I used your json data but you can handle it more effectively. I really suggest you to read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections that document about collections.